# pure-whitespace edits cannot be submitted

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, character-limit

This has been discussed before (e.g. [Only adding whitespace to a question leads to rejection of edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128943/only-adding-whitespace-to-a-question-leads-to-rejection-of-edit)) but the explanations point to something other than the edit.

Every time I try to just add four whitespace characters to convert a code block to actual code, it is rejected with the following error:

> [image]

Is this desired behavior or is there something about my account that prohibits me from making those changes?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing else to improve in such posts?

Comment: Oftentimes there's no way to evaluate whether the code is a good example of the issue at hand (sometimes OP made a small typo) without being able to read it, hence the edit to make SO render it as code

Comment: The preview gives you that chance - no need to submit in order to determine that.

Comment: You can't simultaneously see the edit preview and submit a response though.  Although I could just take a screenshot or open in two tabs ...

Comment: I'd argue that the two _should_ be separate activities. Improving a post is one thing, answering a question is another.

Comment: @Oded "There is absolutely nothing else to improve in such posts?" is that so inconceivable?

Comment: @Oded: Yes. So why isn’t it allowed to improve posts?

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes, it is. Punctuation, grammar, clarification; no question that has code issues can otherwise be absolutely perfect. Someone who pays that much attention to what they write will undoubtedly care enough to know (or to learn) how to indent code.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I could just write "screw flanders" at the end -- that would satisfy the rule :)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker what if there's simply not enough text for the asker to break (ignoring the fact that fixing the formatting in these will trigger the quality filter) ?

Comment: Is it being automatically rejected (character limit?) or review rejected?

Comment: @A.M. automatically rejected.  Someone else pointed out that just saying "rejected" meant that a reviewer rejected, so I changed the title to "cannot be submitted"

Comment: @GeorgeStocker English language graduate (perfect writing) but first time poster on SO (So doesnt know how to format code)

Comment: @JanDvorak By "asker to break" I'm assuming you mean that the question asker didn't write enough? If so; then isn't that a pretty big issue itself? In that case, close the question as unanswerable, or edit it to fill in the blanks; we can do this all day. I'm speaking from experience in editing thousands of posts. It's always possible to improve a post other than just code. Always.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I agree with your heuristics and with the closure, but I also agree with the feature request made here.